# Name of the transparent sticky substance

Tags: plants

What is the name of the transparent sticky substance, which you can discover when you skive a young green stick from a bark?

Comment: Look up sap (noun) and see if that works.

Comment: I know the word "sap" but I don't know the word "skive".  My dictionary says skiving is avoiding work, or else some technical thing you do working with leather.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the word for this is ["sap"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sap).

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1 a** : the fluid part of a plant
>   *specifically* : a watery solution that circulates through a plant's vascular system

Comment: To make this a perfect answer, you would include a reference to a dictionary.  Posts (even correct ones) without references are discouraged, since as far as the reader can tell, it is juts one guy's opinion.

Comment: I added a dictionary definition to your answer, along with a link and citation. Feel free to change it if you'd like. (Different people format such links differently.) But this is an example of the kind of information that should be added to answers like this.